# Writing a parser for Persons in haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm trying to write a parser for a data Person (`data Person`). But I have to write it in just one line using `<$>` and `<*>` and I was trying a lot, but I'm getting really "overtaxed".

The parser type is as usual:

`newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a,String)])`

And I have this function:

`parse :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a`

that returns the first complete parse.

**e.g.**

if I have this easy function:

```
upper :: Parser Char
upper = satisfy isUpper
```

If I run `parse upper "A"` I get `Just 'A'`

I also have a funnier function like this:

```
name :: Parser String
name = (:) <$> (satisfy isUpper) <*> (many $ satisfy isAlpha)
```

which, as you can see, accepts all strings that are literal characters and begin with an upper Letter.

so:

```
*Main> parse name1 "hello"
Nothing
*Main> parse name1 "Hello"
Just "Hello"
```

Until now is everything fine, the only problem is that I have to do something like that for the class (data, type ?!) Person (`data Person`)

so, I have this:

`data Person = Person String deriving (Eq, Show)`

And then, in just one line, I have to write the parser for `Person`, but the name should satisfy the function `name`, it means, the name should be just a chain of literal characters, where the first one is upper case.

And it should work so:

```
> parse parserPerson "Chuck"
 Just (Person "Chuck")
> parse parserPerson "chuck"
 Nothing
```

where:

```
parserPerson :: Parser Person
parserPerson = ???
```

As you can see, bevor "Chuck" there is `Person`, so I've to use somehow `*>` to get it.

And that's it, just a line with `<$>`, `<*>` and `*>` that works that way.

I don't have a clue, and I'm getting crazy with this. Maybe anyone could help me.

**EDIT**

```
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char -- parse a desired character
satisfy p = Parser check
  where
    check (c:s) | p c = [(c,s)] -- successful
    check   _   = [     ] -- no parse
```

and `many` (as `some`) are functions from the `Control.Applicative` [Control.Applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html)

Comment: What are `satisfy` and `many`?

Comment: oh yeah, of course, sorry. I write it now.

Comment: Assuming your parser has a functor instance you should be able to do `parsePerson = Person <$> name`

Comment: Oh man!! So easy was it :D yeah, I have a Functor instance  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tsorn said, the answer was really easy...

```
parserPerson :: Parser Person
parserPerson = Person <$> name1
```

and it works because the Functor Instacnce was defined.

```
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f (Parser p) = Parser $ \s -> map (\(a,b) -> (f a, b)) $ p s
```

Comment: The key here is realizing that `Person` is both a type and a data constructor, the latter being just a function which takes a string argument and returns a value of type `Person`. It may be insightful to define the data type like this instead: `data Person = MkPerson String`, in which case `MkPerson` is a function that takes a string argument and returns a value of type `Person`.

Comment: Thanks dude! And for example, if Person were ```Person String Int``` how should I do for taking the string and the int? I mean, I can have another parser for Numbers, but how it works? so? : ```Person <$> name <*> numberParser``` ? I just wanted to go a little bit "deeper" in haskell and I got some issues :D

Comment: Yes that's the right approach. It relies on the applicative instance.

Comment: For Example, from ```parse parserPerson "Person Chuck 25"``` I would like to get ```Just (Person "Chuck" 25) ```. If I do ```Person <$> name1 <*> natural``` I get  ```Nothing```, but just because 1: Person and 2: the spaces. So, I gotta try to skip the spaces and "eat" person. But I think it's too much bitter now :D

Comment: You could work through the parser tasks in the course https://github.com/data61/fp-course, that should cover enough to do the task you mentioned.